# Cannot scroll using trackpad on Sony Vaio

Tags: 11.10, trackpad, vaio

since upgrading my [vaio notebook](http://www.sony-asia.com/product/vpceb36fg) to Ubuntu 11.10, I am unable to scroll using my trackpad. Tried all means to no avail. Please suggest a step by step process to solve the problem. This has almost left me regretting the upgrade.

looking forward to replies

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```sh
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps
```

It should works now. It's time to make it permanent:

```sh
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/psmouse <<< 'options psmouse proto=imps'
```

That's all.

(That solution was posted **[here](http://envezdelpsiquiatra.wordpress.com/2009/04/24/arreglando-el-fallo-del-touchpad-en-jaunty/)** in Ubuntu Jaunty, but it should work in Oneiric)

Comment: Tried this + also "Pointing Device: PS/2 Mouse" but didn't work (right mouse button worked) - solution: Changed Chipset to PIIX3 .....